# Excel VBA Bloomberg Refreshallstaticdata Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use excel vba to refresh a workbook that contains Bloomberg excel formulas. I am able to have the formulas update by using the below formulas

`Application.run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.run "RefreshallStaticData"`

however, they only update once the sub has completed. I have tried putting in formulas to wait, but from what I have found the Bloomberg formulas will not update until the sub completes, once it completes I can see the formulas updating on the tab. I need to have the formulas update so then I can use the data later in the sub. Is there a way I can have the formulas update without having the sub complete?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use two different Macros. The Frist on consisting of the refresh arguments and the second macro with the calculations, updates etc.
An alternative to this could be: To download the Bloomberg Data directly via VBA.